# How to secure Windows Server 2012 R2 against "open recursive resolver" attack

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, ddos, dns-hosting

I received an email from an ISP stating that our server had participated in a DDOS attack against one of their servers--and that we appear to be running an "open recursive resolver".

The IP address they gave is for one of our development servers, which is running WIndows Server 2012 R2.  I did some googling and followed these instructions (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc771738.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to disable recursion in DNS Manager.  My questions are:

1. Should turning off the recursion option be enough to make sure this does not happen again?
2. Is it OK to delete the DNS Server on this server?  I didn't even know it was apparently installed by default.  We use external DNS servers for everything.  I would like to keep our attack surface minimal in general.

Comment: `Is it OK to delete the DNS Server on this server?` - How would we know that? We don't know why it was installed on that server. Talk to your development team or whatever entity uses this server and ask them why it's installed.

Comment: The server is just being used as a web server, as I mentioned, we only use external DNS servers.  Basically, we did not know that DNS was installed by default--we never went out of our way to install DNS or configure it.  So, to my knowledge we are NOT using the local DNS server.  I just never encountered this before, and want to make sure its not being used for anything else by Windows Server internally etc.

Comment: Well it isn't installed by default, it has to be selected and installed. Why its there we can't tell you. You need to investigate if any of the internal machines are using for DNS. The contents of the dns zones should give you an idea on what it is doing

Comment: Basically: an open recursive resolver means your DNS Server is accessible publicly and is resolving all domains for any who ask it. Block incoming Internet traffic to port 53 in the firewall and configure the DNS server to only listen on internal addresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you I would approach this from the network perspective. Setup a firewall to log to log any traffic to `53/udp and 53/tcp` on the server. Figure out what is using the service.

If no one knows why DNS was installed, and you disable it the only way to know if you **needed** it will be to examine what broke.

Answer (score 0):

As I seen in the comment that the server is used only as a webserver, please allow only the needed port be openned to the server. That move will block the unauthorised use of that DNS.

On small soho firewall many put public server in a open dmz, but with an advanced firewall its more wise to make a public vlan for the server and forward only the required port, like http/https for your case.